# Where do those pipes behind a collector box go

Tags: hvac

So I had to remove my collector box and disinfect because of sewage backup in my condensation line - and my question is what are all those pipes that lead to the condensation box?

I'm trying to figure out if and how I might need to disinfect what was behind the condensation collector box and was wondering where all those little pipes lead from and what those tabs are..  are they all internal sealed pipes to each coil?  Do they pipe directly to the condensate pan in the condenser compartment above?  is it just an open pipe that pipes directly into the air chamber?

Essentially trying to figure out if and how I need to clean these little pipes as well.[image]

Comment: Looks like a heat exchanger/radiator.  Those tabs might be to help pull out the insides(baffles?) of the pipes, but do not pull too hard in case they don't.

Comment: so yeah it does seem like it would be secondary heat exchanger for the furnace - I guess the question I have is is it a closed system or would sewage/flood liquid going up those tubes cause leak out into the main air channel and may cause dirty air?